# Adding group permission to directory without changing group ownership?

Tags: centos

I have a directory called "music" and two groups: music, singers.

I executed

```
chgrp music music
```

I am looking to grant read and write access to the /music directory for the singers group, but I don't want to change the ownership.

Is this possible?

I am a bit confused with chown and chgrp. I believe chown changes ownership for a single user and not a group? and chgrp changes the group?

Is there a way to set group ownership, but grant permissions to another group?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the group with chgrp command. Take a look at the first answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124246/what-command-changes-the-group-setting-for-a-directory)